# SVG path rotate animation - changes position

Tags: html, css, svg, sass, css-animations

I am trying to rotate my 3 paths, but when I do so, it changes the position.

https://codepen.io/jonas2711/pen/XWaOaVM

```
  @keyframes rotate{
  from{transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to{transform: rotate(360deg)}
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is "transform-origin: 35px 35px"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: Just change `transform-origin: 35px 35px;`.

Comment: Sorry, I was jumping to conclusions – I have edited the answer to include Azu's suggestion.

Comment: Thank you @Azu can you explain me why?

Comment: The rect tag has width and height of 71px, this is half.